# Предложение с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: нормы-языка

Помогите переделать предложение с причастным оборотом: В нынешнем году, учитывая специфику предложенной темы, мероприятия в большей степени должны быть направлены не только на повышение правовой грамотности населения и развитие потребительского движения, но и популяризацию среди граждан знаний о принципах полноценного питания...

Comment: @Верьясова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: А где здесь причастный оборот?

Answer (score 3):

К сожалению, не понял, о  какой специфике идёт речь… Но всё равно попробую что-нибудь сочинить.

*В нынешнем году,  **в связи с спецификой  предложенной темы**, мероприятия в большей степени должны быть направлены не **столько** на повышение правовой грамотности населения и развитие потребительского движения, **сколько** на  популяризацию среди граждан знаний о принципах полноценного питания...*

Answer (score 2):

В исходной фразе два осн. недостка: a) учитывая... мероприятия должны быть (= мероприятия сами что-то учитывают и потому должны) и б) недостаёт повторного "на" перед "популяризацию". Если обойтись минимальными изменениями и сохранить деепричастный оборот, можно попробовать так (кто будет учитывать, тому и нужно делать):

Учитывая специфику предложенной темы, мероприятия в этом году нужно направить преимущественно на повышение правовой грамотности населения, а также на популяризацию среди граждан знаний о принципах полноценного питания...